# clear interactive python session when re-running script from emacs

Tags: python, emacs

I've got the following python script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(1, 20, 10)
y = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x**2, y)

plt.ion()
plt.show()
```

To run it from an emacs buffer, I execute the following:

`C-c C-p`  # a new buffer appears with an interactive ipython session

`C-c C-c`  # run the script

I then make a small change to the code in emacs (say multiply the x vector by some constant), and run it again with `C-c C-c`, the following error appears:

> TypeError: unbound method trigger_manager_draw() must be called with
>   _BackendMac instance as first argument (got FigureManagerMac instance instead)

Since it always works the first time around, how can I run the code in a clear/fresh Python session each time I execute `C-c C-c`? Also is `C-c C-p` necessary? Is there a way to simply achieve both steps with only `C-c C-c`?

Comment: Can't reproduce with Emacs 25.1.91.1 at Debian. Assume a Mac issue. Maybe try plain Python?